# Combination of accelation signals from two devices

Tags: discrete-signals, sensor

I have $x_A$, $y_A$, and $z_A$ acceleration signals collected from a smartphone and I call it: set $A$ and I also  have $x_B$, $y_B$, and $z_B$ same acceleration signals from smartwatch: let's call this set $B$. I need to combine them together to obtain set $C$, but since I don't have good knowledge in signal processing I am not sure if it is this logically correct to combine them and take the average of them, or any other way should I follow to have one set of signals instead of having two separate sets?

How to select the set if it is possible? The signals are raw data.

Comment: One search term you could try is "sensor fusion".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You have the movement of the watch and the movement of the phone. You try combine them to get the movement of what exactly?

Comment: Do you try to combine them online, or does offline suffice?

Comment: I am trying to find which combination of devices give optimal result in regard to detect the subject's activities. I have more than these two sensors but I just ask about these two and then if I got an answer then apply it on all. I will combine smartphone with smartwatch, smartphone with sensor placed on upper arm and etc. 

Regarding the online or offline not sure which to use, but after collecting the raw data I want to know if it is better to do the combination after or before extracting features.

Comment: any answer please!!

Answer (score 2):

May be you can find [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of acceleration along x,y, and z direction in SET A and in set B separately and choose the the device which has least variance.

---

[As this Wikipedia page suggests,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_fusion#Example_sensor_fusion_calculations) you can combine the two by weighting by their respective variances.

So, to get $x_C$ simply:
$$
x_C = \frac{1}{\sigma_1^{-2} + \sigma_2^{-2}} \left(  \frac{x_A}{\sigma_1^2} + \frac{x_B}{\sigma_2^2}\right)
$$

Putting some numbers on this, suppose $\sigma^2_1 = 1$ and $\sigma^2_2 = 0.5$, then 
$$
\sigma_3^2 = \frac{1}{\sigma_1^{-2} + \sigma_2^{-2}} = \frac{1}{1 + 2} = \frac{1}{3}
$$
which is a lower variance than either of the individual measurements.

Use the same process to find $y_C$ and $z_C$.

Comment: thank you for your comment, but I need to have both and I want to find a way to combine them and to see how can they give me same result when they are combined comparing to the individual results. What I'm doing is that I am detecting activities from both the smartphone and the smartwatch, and I am able to detect the right activity when using each device's data separate and now I want to know how to combine their signals and run my algorithm to see if it can detect the right activities or not.

Comment: In that case you can mimic kalman filter like thing. What about,

Comment: What about, combined = (set A value)*(1/variance of set A) + (set B value)*(1/variance of set B)  ???

Comment: May I know why the answer has been down voted and the reason why it may not work...

Comment: I am waiting to know too, not sure why somebody voted down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just wondering about the picking of the values like you have chosen 1 and 0.5, are these random values or should be related to the collected x, y, z signals.  

Also, I want to know if the suggested solution would work if I apply it after extracting the features fro each accelerometer's signals.

Mean of the magnitude data 
Maximum value. 
Minimum value.
Standard Deviation value for each axis (x, y, and z).
Average Standard Deviation over 3 axes.
Root mean squared acceleration (RMS). 
The sum of height of frequency component below 5 Hz
Number of peaks in spectrum

Comment: Thanks Peter, still waiting your answer regarding the picking of the values like you have chosen 1 and 0.5, are these random values or should be related to the collected x, y, z signals.

Comment: They should be related to the collected values x,y,z signals. Sigma1^2 is variance of acceleration values in X direction which you got using smart phone. Signa2^2 is the variance of acceleration values you got using smart watch. He took random values to show you that if you combine signals in the above mentioned way, you get better result than when you use the sensor values alone. Read the values. Before you combine them, variance was 1 and 0.5. After you combine the variance is 0.333 which is good. You don't use 1 or 0.5, you calculate variance using X,y,z signal values